# Regular expression with pattern repetition within pattern

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match the below string using regular expressions

String:

```
These are my variables -abc $def -geh $ijk for case1

These are my variables -lmn $opq -rst $uvw for case2
```

Pattern:

```
These\s+are\s+my\s+variables(?:\s*-(\w+)\s+\$(\w+))*\s+for\s+(case\d)
```

I could match successfully the above string with my pattern but the problem is that I am unable to catch the groups as I intend. My attempts are giving me the results as below

```
geh, ijk, case1

rst, uvw, case2
```

I wanted the groups output as below

```
abc, def, geh, ijk, case1

lmn, opq, rst, uvw, case2
```

How to approach for this issue?

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2chH9M/4)

Comment: Don't use `?:` for the first group as that's a non matching group.

Comment: Use PyPi regex and use the same pattern - you will get the variables in `.captures(1)` and `.captures(2)`.

Comment: When repeating capturing groups, only the last iteration is stored in the resulting match. If it's always four, unroll your pattern - otherwise you'll need a two step solution.

Comment: should those words  always go as last six params at the end of the string?

Comment: @Sebastian Actually the number of variables are dynamic, so I cant unroll the pattern. So how to proceed?

Comment: You might want to follow @Wiktors advice and use the PyPi module. If that's not an option - match all the stuff between `variables` and `for` and then e.g. split by ` [-$]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/2016.11.18) and use the same regex you are using as is shown below:

```
import regex
s = 'These are my variables -abc $def -geh $ijk for case1'
rx = regex.compile(r'These\s+are\s+my\s+variables(?:\s*-(\w+)\s+\$(\w+))*\s+for\s+(case\d)')
print([x.captures(1) for x in rx.finditer(s)])
# => [abc, geh]
print([x.captures(2) for x in rx.finditer(s)])
# => [def, ijk]
```

Else, capture all the options with

```
These\s+are\s+my\s+variables((?:\s*-\w+\s+\$\w+)*)\s+for\s+(case\d)
```

(see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/lDuy09/1)), and get the separate values as Step 2.

```
import re
r = r"These\s+are\s+my\s+variables((?:\s*-\w+\s+\$\w+)*)\s+for\s+(case\d)"
s = "These are my variables -abc $def -geh $ijk for case1"
m = re.search(r, s)
if m:
    print(re.findall(r'-(\w+)', m.group(1)))
    print(re.findall(r'\$(\w+)', m.group(1)))
    print(m.group(2))
```

See the [Python demo](http://ideone.com/Jqa0O6)

Comment: Thanks @Wiktor. Hope this will be helpful for my scenario

Comment: I also added the `re` solution as well.

Comment: Yes, I also have implemented using this two step process for extracting out the variables. Thanks for the solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following alternative approach using `str.lstrip` and `str.split` functions(it will return a list of parameter sets for each line):

```
s = '''These are my variables -abc $def -geh $ijk for case1

These are my variables -lmn $opq -rst $uvw for case2'''

params = [[p.lstrip('$-') for p in l.split()[4:] if p != 'for'] for l in s.split('\n') if l]

print(params)
```

The output:

```
[['abc', 'def', 'geh', 'ijk', 'case1'], ['lmn', 'opq', 'rst', 'uvw', 'case2']]
```

Comment: This solution looks good but I would like to implement using regular expressions for my scenario. Thanks for the new idea of implementation!!